# Indesign – add symbol before first and after last paragraphs of the same style

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I have several paragraphs with the same style. I'd like to auto-add new line before the first paragraph and new line after last paragraph of the same style. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

N.B. The necessary case – it should be **the same** style 'cause it will be processed via Markdown.

Comment: By "a new line" do you mean "a space which is the equivalent of hitting return once"? (This is also not a "symbol," so you should edit your title for clarity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into InDesign that will automatically insert a newline (or extra space before or space after) only to the first and last paragraphs of a given style.

If this is something you will be doing a lot, it could certainly be done with a script that was either set up to start with InDesign or invoked manually. The best place to ask about scripting would be on the [InDesign scripting forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting) on adobe.com. In my experience, scripters are an incredibly helpful bunch, and since something like this would not be complex, you'll likely get as an answer something you can use right away.